# Approximating a curve with a parabole at a given point

Tags: taylor-expansion, conic-sections

I wonder if such a task is possible: we have a curve defined implicitly with:

$x^4+y^3-xy-1=0\qquad(1)$

I want to find a parabola in a general form of:

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$

... which approximates the curve the best at the point $(1,1)$.

My idea was to treat the equation $(1)$ as a function $F(x,y)$ and expand it into a Taylor polynomial $W(x,y)$ of a degree 2:

$W(x,y)=F(1,1)+df(1,1)(x-1,y-1)+\frac{1}{2}d^2f(1,1)(x-1,y-1)$

... where:

$d^nf(1,1)(x-x_0,y-y_0)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}\frac{\partial^nf}{\partial x^{n-i}\partial y^i}(x_0,y_0)\cdot(x-x_0)^{n-i}(y-y_0)^i$

In the end I got the following formula for the "parabola":

$3(x-1)+2(y-1)+12(x-1)^2-2(x-1)(y-1)+6(y-1)^2=\\=6x^2-xy+3y^2-8x-3y+3$

However to my surprise it turned out to be an ... ellipse instead:

[image]

The question is, is it the only valid answer (if it is correct at all)? Can I "explode" this ellipse into a parabola that would satisfy my needs? And since we're at it, a side-question: what about transforming it into a hyperbola, is it possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

(edited 5.6.2014): If $F(x,y)=0$ represents a curve, then it is not true that its  second order Taylor approximation in $(a,b)$ is $dF(a,b)(x-a, y-b)+d^2 F(a,b)(x-a, y-b)=0$. (Note, that if $d^2 F$ is positive definite, it will always be an ellipse.)

You could compute derivatives of the implicite function $y(x)$ in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$. Differentiate your original equation and you get $4x^3+3y^2 y' - y - xy'=0$, which implies $y'(1)=-3/2$. Similarly, you compute $y''(1)$ and your parabole is then just $y=y(1)+(x-1) y'(1) + \frac{y''(1)}{2} (x-1)^2$.

However, if you are not interested in properties of the function $y(x)$ but rather in some geometric properties of the zero set itself, then you should specify more exactly what you mean by "best approximation" and why should such thing be a parabola at all. One approximation possibility could be the [osculating circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle), which is (among other properties) invariant wrt. Euclidean transformations of your curve.

Comment: First: I'm not quite sure what you mean in your first paragraph. The approximation **is** good, because after summing up $dF+\frac{1}{2}d^2F+\frac{1}{6}d^3F+\frac{1}{24}d^4F$ I restored the original curve to every detail which is a polynomial of degree 4.

Second: I don't want to 'solve' the exercise, but to solve the problem I came up with. And by restricting the curve to the form of $y(x)=...$ you obliterated my idea - the parabola is supposed to be tangent (flush) with the curve and thus is not going to be a function (it's going to be tilted a bit).

Comment: Locally, your equation defines implicitely a function $y(x)$. If you don't consider the second order Taylor approximation to be the "best (local) quadratic approximation", you should then define more clearly what you mean by the words "approximates the curve the best". Osculating circle, maybe?